# Is a start and End date lying between a project start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to find if a particular year falls in between two dates:
Eg. Fiscal year is `April- March`
Project Start Date: `1 April 2023`
Project End Date: `26 March 2026`

I want columns stating:

```
FY23-24: Yes
FY24-25: Yes
FY25-26: Yes
FY26-27:No
```

Please share excel formula if possible and not python based.

Comment: It seems your data `FY23-24` entered as text. You can't compare text with dates. Enter data as year value.

Comment: Compare a date to be greater or less than other dates.

Comment: It will be an if statement where under Fy23-24 I get Yes/No accordingly

Comment: It would be good if you would start accepting answers that helped you. People have made an effort on your behalf but you are not reciprocating.

Answer (score 1):

You may give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(dt,DATE(--"20"&TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A4,"-"),"FY"),4,30),
IF(AND(dt>=$B$1,dt<=$B$2),"Yes","No"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below Excel formula. As show in screen shot, I have used helper rows to indicate start and end date of each financial year.

```
=IF(OR(AND($A4>=C$1,$A4<=C$2),AND($A4<C$1,$B4>=C$1)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]